# RxJava/RxScala async code inside Observer.onNext

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-scala

Let's assume that you want to store events from some stream into the database and a client library to that database is asynchronous.

E.g. there is a method `writeEvent(event: MyEvent): Future[Boolean]` that you have to call inside `onNext` of your observer when the next event is emitted. Is there a good way to do this otherwise than blocking on the `Future`?

*The only way that I currently see on how to implement this, is to create some custom `Scheduler` that allows me to return thread to the pool, until async code inside `onNext` is complete.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to block like that inside your `onNext` subscriber callback, that would defeat Rx. It can be chained together in a more idiomatic way.

I don't work with Futures much, but I wonder if `Observable.from(Future)` would work:

```
someStream
    .flatMap(evt => Observable.from(writeEvent(evt)))
    .subscribe(
        next => ...,
        err => ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that it could work, I'll try it and report later.